# grid.dataItem(row) is returning undefined

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

Using a kendo data grid, i am adding the model value in the databound event for a column

However the model is returned as undefined ,

here is teh code ,

```
         let grid = $('#TypeGrid').data('kendoGrid');
                            grid.tbody.find('.progress').each(function() {
                                let row = $(this).closest('tr');
                                let model = grid.dataItem(row);//undefined
                                $(this).kendoProgressBar({
                                    max: 100,
                                    value: model.value
                                });
                            });
```

not sure why i get undefined , i do get the row  but grid.dataItem(row) is undefined

Comment: Is row itself undefined, or grid.dataItem(row)?

Comment: grid.dataItem(row), i do get back the row, i dont get the model

Comment: Can you paste the console logged values for "this" (inside the function), grid and "row" please?

Comment: Here is the " row"       [tr, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: div.progress]
0
:
tr
context
:
div.progress
length
:
1
prevObject
:
jQuery.fn.init(1)
__proto__
:
Object(0)

Comment: this = <div class="progress"></div>

Answer (score 0):

```
 let grid = $('#TypeGrid').data('kendoGrid');
                                grid.tbody.find('.progress').each(function(index, row) {
                                    let row = $(this).closest('tr');
                                    let model = grid._data[index];
                                    $(this).kendoProgressBar({
                                        max: 100,
                                        value: model.value
                                    });
                                });
```

Comment: Try using [index] in for each loop and use grid._data[index] instead of grid.dataItem(row)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).